# Sending XPath a variable from Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have an XPath expression that searches for a static value. In this example, "test" is that value:

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//doc[contains(., 'test')]/*/text()");
```

How can I pass a variable instead of a fixed string? I use Java with Eclipse. Is there a way to use the value of a Java `String` to declare an XPath variable?

Answer (score 22):

You can define a variable resolver and have the evaluation of the expression resolve variables such as `$myvar`, for example:

`XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//doc[contains(., $myVar)]/*/text()");`

There's a fairly good explanation [here](http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=xml.xpath). I haven't actually done this before myself, so I might have a go and provide a more complete example.

---

Update:

Given this a go, works a treat. For an example of a very simple implementation, you could define a class that returns the value for a given variable from a map, like this:

```
class MapVariableResolver implements XPathVariableResolver {
  // local store of variable name -> variable value mappings
  Map<String, String> variableMappings = new HashMap<String, String>();

  // a way of setting new variable mappings 
  public void setVariable(String key, String value)  {
    variableMappings.put(key, value);
  }

  // override this method in XPathVariableResolver to 
  // be used during evaluation of the XPath expression      
  @Override
  public Object resolveVariable(QName varName) {
    // if using namespaces, there's more to do here
    String key = varName.getLocalPart();
    return variableMappings.get(key);
  }
}
```

Now, declare and initialise an instance of this resolver in the program, for example

```
MapVariableResolver vr = new MapVariableResolver() ;
vr.setVariable("myVar", "text");
...
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
xpath.setXPathVariableResolver(vr);
```

Then, during evaluation of the XPath expression `XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//doc[contains(., $myVar)]/*/text()");`, the variable `$myVar` will be replaced with the string `text`.

Nice question, I learnt something useful myself!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to evaluate Java (or whatever else PL variables in XPath). In C# (don't know Java well) I'll use:

```
    string XPathExpression = 
"//doc[contains(., " + myVar.ToString() + ")]/*/text()";

    XmlNodelist result = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(XPathExpression);
```

Comment: I find simple inlining of variables a bit cumbersome, compared to the possibility of using true variables. Besides, you'll have to think of syntactical integrity (e.g. what if `myVar` contains quotes? etc)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170887/xpath-and-variables#3170932), that explains well how to do it with the standard Java API, you could also use a third-party library like [jOOX](http://code.google.com/p/joox/) that can handle variables in a simple way:

```
List<String> list = $(doc).xpath("//doc[contains(., $1)]/*", "test").texts();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something similar to @brabster:

```
// expression: "/message/PINConfiguration/pinValue[../keyReference=$keyReference]";

Optional<Node> getNode(String xpathExpression, Map<String, String> variablesMap)
        throws XPathExpressionException {
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    xpath.setXPathVariableResolver(qname -> variablesMap.get(qname.getLocalPart()));
    return Optional.ofNullable((Node) xpath.evaluate(xpathExpression, document, 
            XPathConstants.NODE));
}

Optional<Node> getNode(String xpathExpression) throws XPathExpressionException {
    return getNode(xpathExpression, Collections.emptyMap());
}
```