# compiling XPath expression issue

Tags: java, xml, xpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending XPath a variable from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170887/sending-xpath-a-variable-from-java)

When I run this expression:

```
    XPathExpression xpe = xpath.compile("//bb[name/text()='k2']/value");
```

It works fine.

But when I try to plant my own variable (instead of 'k2') like this:

```
    XPathExpression xpe = xpath.compile("//bb[name/text()=" + c_name +"]/value");
```

tt doesn't work.

I assume the problem is that the working expression syntax contain 'k2' while the second dont appear that way.

Any ideas how to plant the variable correctly? i tried putting String and Character[] both dont work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"//bb[name/text()='" + c_name +"']/value"
```

Note the single quotes surrounding the reference to `c_name`.

You could argue that the alternative using `String.format()`

```
 "//bb[name/text()='%s']/value".format(c_name)
```

is more readable.

As dogbane notes, this won't work if the variable value contains quotes itself. For a more complex but safer solution see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170887/sending-xpath-a-variable-from-java).

Comment: -1 won't work if name is `Scarlett O'Hara`.

Comment: Of course. Noted and referenced an appropriate solution

Comment: Constructing XPath expressions by string concatenation leaves you exposed to injection attacks. It's much better to use variables.

Comment: @Michael - acknowledged and that's why I referenced the additional answer. Of course your exposure to attacks is dependent upon your source of variable texts, and consequently different solutions are appropriate for different scenarios