# How to replace a value in xpath expression

Tags: java, xml

I have a XML file in which a node's value is a xpath exp

**//n-document[./n-docbody/TTA-DOCINFO/TTA-ANCESTOR[@value=#UID#]]**.

I need to get this xpath exp in my java code(which i am able to) and replace the **UID** in the xpath with an existing string variable value.

For ex:- if the string variable is "XXX", my xpath should become:

```
//n-document[./n-docbody/TTA-DOCINFO/TTA-ANCESTOR[@value=XXX]]
```

How do i achieve this.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: You want to use a variable in your expression. This has been answered here already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170887/sending-xpath-a-variable-from-java