# Xpath compile not handling ' apostrophe

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following code to find type of required node.

```
  private void handleDemote(CalendarCustomization calendar)
{
    String name = calendar.getName();
    Node node = (Node)reader.read("/APIBusinessObjects/Calendar[Name='" + name + "']/Type", XPathConstants.NODE);
   ...}

  public Object read(String expression, QName returnType)
{
    try
    {
        XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(expression);
        return xPathExpression.evaluate(xmlDocument, returnType);
    }
    catch (XPathExpressionException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The xml which I am trying to parse has te following content

```
 <Calendar>
    <BaseCalendarObjectId xsi:nil="true" />
    <HoursPerDay>8</HoursPerDay>
    <HoursPerMonth>173.3</HoursPerMonth>
    <HoursPerWeek>40</HoursPerWeek>
    <HoursPerYear>2080</HoursPerYear>
    <IsDefault>0</IsDefault>
    <IsPersonal>0</IsPersonal>
    <Name>test&apos;sCal</Name>
```

The getName function is returning me the test'sCal.So name =test'sCal .
The problem is with the apostrophe as the expression contains single extra quote. it shortens the name causing the expression to become wrong.
Please suggest .

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3170932/423105), you should be able to use XPath variables in Java, and that is the correct way to go about this.

You can define a generic variable resolver:

```
class MapVariableResolver implements XPathVariableResolver {
  // local store of variable name -> variable value mappings
  Map<String, String> variableMappings = new HashMap<String, String>();

  // a way of setting new variable mappings 
  public void setVariable(String key, String value)  {
    variableMappings.put(key, value);
  }

  // override this method in XPathVariableResolver to 
  // be used during evaluation of the XPath expression      
  @Override
  public Object resolveVariable(QName varName) {
    // if using namespaces, there's more to do here
    String key = varName.getLocalPart();
    return variableMappings.get(key);
  }
}
```

modify your `read()` method like this:

```
public Object read(String expression, QName returnType, XPathVariableResolver vr)
{
    try
    {
        xPath.setXPathVariableResolver(vr != null ? vr : new MapVariableResolver());
        XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(expression);
        return xPathExpression.evaluate(xmlDocument, returnType);
    }
    catch (XPathExpressionException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then do this:

```
String name = calendar.getName();
MapVariableResolver vr = new MapVariableResolver() ;
vr.setVariable("name", name);

Node node = (Node)reader.read("/APIBusinessObjects/Calendar[Name = $name]/Type",
                              XPathConstants.NODE, vr);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a general solution (i.e. when you don't know whether the input will contain single quotes, double quotes, or both):

1. If you have XPath 2.0, which I guess you don't judging by your Java code, you could replace each single quote with a pair of single quotes (in string delimited by single quotes, as yours is). (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13494929/423105).)
2. Otherwise, you can use `concat()` within your XPath expression to concatenate `'"'` and `"'"` with the rest of your string as needed. See [The Perils of XPath Expressions (Specifically, Escaping Quotes)](http://kushalm.com/the-perils-of-xpath-expressions-specifically-escaping-quotes). So with your example data, your XPath expression would come out as:

-

```
 /APIBusinessObjects/Calendar[Name = concat('test', "'", 'sCal')]
```

Then it's up to you to write a Java function to transform `test'sCal` into `'test', "'", 'sCal'`. Thankfully, `concat()` will take as many arguments as you give it.