# XPath expression using XPathVariableResolver

Tags: java

I am trying to do same thing to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170887/sending-xpath-a-variable-from-java#3170932) but I am getting the XPathExpressionException,
"javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token."

My expression seems to be incorrect.
Can someone help me with this please?

```
for (String tag : tags) {
MapVariableResolver vr = new MapVariableResolver();
vr.addVariable(new QName(null, tag),tag);
xPath.setXPathVariableResolver(vr);
StringBuffer expression = new StringBuffer("//$tag/text()");
XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile(expression.toString());
nodeList = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a variable based on `tag`'s value rather than on the "tag" string :

```
vr.addVariable(new QName(null, tag),tag);
```

Use this instead :

```
vr.addVariable(new QName(null, "tag"),tag);
```